# How to pass context defined in setting TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS to my custom views

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I'm having this problem while using Django Social Auth. I Have this template.

```
{% block content %}
<div id="content-main">
    <ul>
        {% for name in social_auth.backends %}
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" name %}">{{ name|title }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

which is rendered correctly if I use the standard urlpattern (it's the login page)

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

but if I use my custom view how do I pass the context which is defined in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

This is my view and the entry in the `settings.py` file

```
def login(request):
    t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')
    c = Context( {} )
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
)
```

it makes sense that in my view the `context` is empty, I pass it an empty object, what should I do to pass the correct `context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the template using `RequestContext` and return the response.
This is generally done as:

```
def someview(request):
    context = { }
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', context,
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

More documentation at [Subclassing RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).